# Not able to figure out the exact PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of postgreSQL data which looks like the one in the attached pic(Pic1-Sample Data) :

[image: Pic 1-Sample Data]

custom_field column would identify if the row entry is 'Department ID' or 'High Priority Role?' and the first six digits of text_value column would give the department codes.
As you can see value in the text_value column is 'Yes' wherever the custom_field is 'High Priority Role?'
Now my requirement is to extract only those records where custom_field is 'High Priority Role'. This sounds very simple but it should also have the 'Department ID' attached to it.

NOTE: job_id is not unique. Each job_id corresponding to 'High Priority Role?' would also have a duplicate entry for which the value in custom_field would be 'Department ID'(see attached Pic 2 for reference).

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select
    a.*,
    b.display_value as department
from (
    select
        *
    from
        <table>
    where
        custom_field = 'High Priority Role?'
) a
inner join
    <table> b
on
    a.job_id = b.job_id
where
    b.custom_field != 'High Priority Role?'
group by
    a.job_id,
    a.custom_field,
    a.float_value,
    a.date_value,
    a.display_value,
    a.text_value,
    a.unit,
    b.display_value
```

I've tested in MariaDB, not PostgreSQL, but it should work.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/62ca4/3/0

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `join`:

```
select t.*, left(t2.text_value, 6) as department_id
from t join
     t t2
     on t.job_id = t2.job_id and
        t.custom_field  = 'High Priority Role?' and
        t2.custom_field <> 'High Priority Role?';
```

This assumes that there is exactly one matching job with the department id.

If there are multiple, then go for a lateral join:

```
select t.*, left(t2.text_value, 6) as department_id
from t, lateral
     (select t2.*
      from t t2
      where t.job_id = t2.job_id and
            t.custom_field  = 'High Priority Role?' and
            t2.custom_field <> 'High Priority Role?'
      fetch first 1 row only  -- no `order by` because any match will do
     ) t2;
```